# Mysql function change to default value automatically after restart mysql server

Tags: mysql

If I restart the mysql server, it changes the value to default value automatically.

```
mysql> show global variables like 'log_bin_trust_function_creators';
+---------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                   | Value |
+---------------------------------+-------+
| log_bin_trust_function_creators | OFF   |
+---------------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = ON;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I would like to make this function ON no matter what happen.

Is there way to make it the my value to default value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the [`log-bin-trust-function-creators`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_bin_trust_function_creators) option in an [option file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/option-files.html) (or use the `--log-bin-trust-function-creators` argument to *`mysqld`* on the command-line if you prefer).